# Error in passing PHP associative array to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to pass this associative array to JavaScript:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [topicid] => 38 [topic] => Dad ) [1] => Array ( [topicid] => 6 [topic] => What did you eat? ) [2] => Array ( [topicid] => 4 [topic] => What have you done? ) [3] => Array ( [topicid] => 43 [topic] => He ) [4] => Array ( [topicid] => 28 [topic] => I doubt it ) [5] => Array ( [topicid] => 10 [topic] => What made you feel good ) [6] => Array ( [topicid] => 12 [topic] => Say to yourself ) [7] => Array ( [topicid] => 29 [topic] => I doubt myself ) )
```

In PHP file:

```
$topicsjson=json_encode($topics);
echo "<script>var topicsjson = $topicsjson; </script>";
```

In JavaScript file:

```
document.write(topicsjson);
```

It gives me this result:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Nope, you miss nothing. `topicsjson` is an array of objects. The default string representation of objects is `[object Object]`. Since you are using `document.write`, all elements of the array are converted to strings. If you want to inspect the variable, then use the console and `console.log`. There is nothing wrong with your data, just the way you look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP generates JavaScript like the following:

```
<script>var topicsjson = [{"topicid":38,"topic":"Dad"},{"topicid":6,"topic":"What did you eat?"},{"topicid":4},{"topic":"What have you done?"}]; </script>
```

Use two for loops to iterate over the contents of `topicsjson`.

```
var length = topicsjson.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (var key in topicsjson[i]) {
        document.write(key + ": " + topicsjson[i][key] + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BqB5/1/)

Comment: It's an array of objects. The way how to iterate over object properties is to use a `for...in` loop. This as nothing to do with arrays. If any, then arrays in JavaScript are actually objects. So don't get too confusing here ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the feedback. I simplified my answer.

Comment: Thanks, well explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
document.write(topicsjson.toString());
```

Comment: That will give the same output. `toString()` is called implicitly.

Comment: sadly, @FelixKling is right. toString gives no different answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this example](http://phpro.org/classes/PHP-Recursive-Array-To-XML-With-DOM.html), converting to XML, which can be parsed [from Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

Comment: I heard that XML is horrible, but is it?

Comment: Horrible how? In addition to DOM representation using DOMParser, XML also has xpath, which can be pretty handy, I don't think there's an equivalent for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the source, Luke](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html). Don't read the contents of the variable with `document.write`. Using your web browser of choice, see the source code of the generated PHP file at this line:

```
echo "<script>var topicsjson = $topicsjson; </script>";
```